# Value not reflecting on the Progress Bar

Tags: c#

Friends, this is my code(below). I'm not able to figure out why the change in value is not reflected on the Progress Bar.

```
    void Code()
    {
        string key;
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++)
                    for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++)
                        for (int m = 0; m < 26; m++)
                        {
                            key = (char)(65 + i) + " " + j.ToString() + " " + (char)(65 + k) + " " + l.ToString() + " " + (char)(65 + m);
                            File.AppendAllText("D:\\Codes.txt", key + Environment.NewLine);
                            val = (i + 1) * (j + 1) * (k + 1) * (l + 1) * (m + 1);
                            MyProgressBar.Value = val;
                            MyProgressBar.Text = (val * 100 / 1757600).ToString() + "%";
                            if (val == 1757600)                                                                    
                                MessageBox.Show("Code generation completed");
                        }
    }
```

The value and text properties of Progress Bar remains the same which was at the For Load. PLease help me out in this.
Thanx in advance for your valuable comments . . .

Comment: Your code is in busy loop. Put your work to a Backgroundworker.

Comment: Wow, this is going to be hell to maintain.

Comment: I also wanted to know that such a block of code requires lot of CPU processing power... How to optimize the same....???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you update it for every value change it would still block the UI.
And this File.AppendAllText is the slowest part of your code..
if i comment it out it runs to the end in some seconds..
Wouldn you like to try to save all the codes to an Array and after that print all of them at one time?
I guess this will be a little bit faster.

```
                    string[] key = new string[1757600];

            private void backgroundWorker3_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                int val = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                    {
                        for (int k = 0; k < 26; k++)
                        {
                            for (int l = 0; l < 10; l++)
                            {
                                for (int m = 0; m < 26; m++)
                                {
                                    key[val] = (char) (65 + i) + " " + j.ToString() + " " + (char) (65 + k) + " " + l.ToString() + " " +
                                          (char) (65 + m);
                                    //File.AppendAllText("D:\\Codes.txt", key + Environment.NewLine);
                                    //val = (i + 1)*(j + 1)*(k + 1)*(l + 1)*(m + 1);
                                    val++;
                                }
                            }
                    backgroundWorker3.ReportProgress(val);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            private void backgroundWorker3_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                MyProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
                MyProgressBar.Text = e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%";
                //if (e.ProgressPercentage == 1757600)
            }

            private void backgroundWorker3_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
            {
                File.WriteAllLines("D:\\Codes.txt", key);
                MessageBox.Show("Code generation completed");
            }
```

This code only needs some seconds ;)

Comment: if this answer solved your problem it would be nice if you accept it. If not just keep questioning ;)

Answer (score 1):

your code is blocking the UI thread so that is why it does not update.  You need to use a background thread of some kind that fires events that tells the UI thread to update.  google "background processing c#" for some details.

Comment: Yae got it...:-) Thanx Pete...
I also wanted to know that such a block of code requires lot of CPU processing power...
How to optimize the same....???

Comment: It's not that it takes a lot of cpu, it's that it doesn't let go of the cpu and therefore blocks the UI thread.  This is true in pretty much all languages I know of. there always needs to be a separate thread for the UI

Answer (score 0):

ProgressBar can take values from 0 to 100

```
MyProgressBar.Value = (val * 100 / 1757600);
```

Comment: I thougth it had `Minimum` and `Maximum` Property

Comment: Sorry Mr.L.B, I've not mentioned in my code but actually I have already declared these values, I mean MyProgressBar.Minimum = 0 and MyProgressBar.Maximum = 1757600. And if still, if I'm wrong in anything, like the style of my programming or the method m approaching, you can correct me...:-)

Comment: @HeinRichardSonButt My comment was for Abdallah Nasir, I commented under your question about what you should do.

Comment: Great, Then I take my words back :)